# Divs falling out of wrapper

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to this so I apologise if this is a simple thing. I seem to be unable to keep the bottom div inside the wrapper, even though it closes after. I've validated the code and this hasn't helped. Please can someone cast some light on where I'm going wrong? Many thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans:300|Raleway:300,700|Droid+Serif:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=0.95; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;"/>

<link href="/css/simplegrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<link href="css/a_main_structure.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/birthgently.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/menu_styling.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Optima' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">
a:link {
    color: #8A8A8A;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    color: #8A8A8A;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #5F5F5F;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:active {
    color: #5F5F5F;
    text-decoration: none;
}
body {
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
</style>

</head>


<body text="#000000" link="#0000ff" dir="ltr" lang="en-GB">

<div id="container">
 <div id="content">
  <div class="wrapper">


<div class="width_100_percent" align="center">
 <div class="headerStretch">
  <img src="images/birthgently-topstrip.jpg" width="960" height="232" alt="alt tag change me"/>
 </div>
</div>


    <div align="center">
    <div class="menuback">
    <div class="paddingtop8px">
    <nav>
        <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
              <ul align="centre">
                <li><a href="test_index_css.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="hypnobirthing-class.html">Weekly Class</a></li>
                <li><a href="hypnobirthing-course.html">The Course</a></li>
                <li><a href="about-hypnobirthing.html">Hypnobirthing</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact-me.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="bookings.html">Bookings</a></li>
              </ul>   
    </nav>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>



<br />


<div class="width_100_percent">
<div class="width7_percent">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="width86_percent"><div class="headerStretch"><img src="images/about-hypnobirthing.jpg" width="800" height="469" alt="alt tag change me" /></div></div>
<div class="width7_percent">&nbsp;</div>
</div>


<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />


<div class="clear_both">
<div class="width_100_percent">
<br />
<br />
<div class="width15_percent">&nbsp;</div>
<div align="center" class="width70_percent">
    <div align="left"><h1 class="contentheadings">The principles of Hypno-birthing</h1>

    </div>
    <p align="left" class="bodytext">Giving birth calmly, safely and gently is every woman's and every baby's birth right. A woman's body has been perfectly designed to give birth to her baby. Free of fear, stress and anxiety her body is able to work in synchrony with her baby to naturally produce a beautiful blend of birthing hormones. <br/>
    <br/>

    When a woman is calm and relaxed the muscles which assist in the birth her baby are able to work harmoniously and effectively which means she has an easier, more gentle birth that is often also accompanied by a significant reduction in pain. These wonderful birthing hormones and muscles help to ensure that a woman can have the amazing, beautiful and profound experience that nature intended birth to be.    
</p>
</div>
<div class="width15_percent">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>




<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />




<div class="clear_both">
<div class="width_100_percent">
<div class="width29_percentquotes-right">
<img src="images/open-quotes.jpg" width="30" height="20" alt=""/> If the birth is calm, gentle & drug free for you, it's also calm, gentle & drug free for your baby - K Graves <img src="images/close-quotes.jpg" width="30" height="20" alt=""/></div>
<div align="center" class="width50_percent">
  <div align="left">
    <p class= "bodytext">Hypno-birthing is not about training mothers to give birth. It is about helping woman to release fear and anxiety and it teaches them how to use self-hypnosis and relaxation so their bodies and minds can relax and they can birth their babies gently. <br />
      <br />
      Hypno-birthing is now widely recognised by birth professionals and is regularly discussed in the media. Hypno-birthing is commonly accepted as an effective approach to childbirth with many midwives training in the technique having witnessed  'hypno-births' first-hand.  </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="width15_percent">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>



<div class="clear_both">
<div class="width_100_percent">
<br />
<br />
<div class="width15_percent">&nbsp;</div>
<div align="center" class="width70_percent">
    <div align="left">
      <h2 class="contentsubheadings">The History of Hypno-birthing</h2>

    </div>
    <p align="left" class="bodytext">More natural and gentle approaches to childbirth including hypno-birthing began in modern times with the work, amongst others, of Dr Grantly Dick-Read, an obstetrician working in England in the early 19th century. His careful observations of women giving birth led him to develop the theory of the 'fear-tension-pain syndrome'.   
</p>
</div>
<div class="width15_percent">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>




<div class="clear_both">
<div class="width_100_percent"><br />
<div class="width15_percent">&nbsp;</div>
<div align="center" class="width50_percent">
  <div align="left">

<p class="bodytext">Having witnessed women giving birth easily, calmly and comfortably he concluded that what made the process of birth painful was fear. Fear caused tension in the woman's body and disrupted the natural processes of labour and birth. Dr Dick-Read documented the negative effect of fear on childbirth.  In his books he argued that childbirth did not have to be the painful ordeal that women had been led to believe they must suffer. He suggested that when fear is not present a woman can give birth comfortably and pain-free.</p></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="width35_percent">
<div class="headerStretch">
<div class="image-pad-left"><img src="images/about-hypno.jpg" width="265" height="177" /></div></div></div>

<div class="width15_percent">&nbsp;</div>




<div class="clear_both">
<div class="width_100_percent">
<div class="width29_percentquotes-right">
<img src="images/open-quotes.jpg" width="30" height="20" alt=""/> My dream is that every woman, everywhere, will know the joy of a truly safe, comfortable, and satisfying birthing for herself and her baby.  Marie Mongan <img src="images/close-quotes.jpg" width="30" height="20" alt=""/></div>
<div align="center" class="width50_percent">
  <div align="left">
    <p class= "bodytext">Unfortunately the view that labour and birth are painful and traumatic continues to be one which is still widely circulated in the media. Even amongst well meaning friends and family the negative view often persists and pregnant women are frequently bombarded with negative and fear evoking images and stories..</p><br />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="width15_percent">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="clear_both">
<div class="width_100_percent">
<br />
<br />
<div class="width15_percent">&nbsp;</div>
<div align="center" class="width70_percent">
    <div align="left">
      <h2 class="contentsubheadings">Getting past fear</h2>

    </div>
    <p align="left" class="bodytext">One of the main elements of hypno-birthing is the removal of such fears and the use of positive images, positive language and positive affirmations about birth. Marie Mongon, an American hypnotherapist was one of the first people to use the phrase HypnoBirthing. She developed a teaching program for parents to be which she brought to the UK in the early 90's. Since then hypno-birthing has gained in popularity and many practitioners including Katherine Graves have gone on to adapt and enhance hypno-birthing techniques specifically for the UK. 
There are now many hypno-birthing practitioners and whilst each have a slightly different approach the key elements of hypno-birthing remain the same - free of fear and tension a woman can give birth to her baby calmly, safely, gently.</p>

</div>
<div class="width15_percent">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>



<div class="clear_both">
<div class="width_100_percent"><br />
<div class="width15_percent">&nbsp;</div>
<div align="center" class="width50_percent">
  <div align="left"><h2 class="contentsubheadings">birthgently classes
  </h2>
    <ul type="square">
                <li type="square" class="bullets">
<p class="bodytext">teaches deep relaxation which keeps you and your birth partner free of stress and fear</p></li>
                 <li type="square" class="bullets">
        <p class="bodytext"> facilitates your body's production of powerful, natural pain relieving endorphins and feel good hormones</p></li>
                <li type="square" class="bullets">
        <p class="bodytext"> helps to shorten the length of the first stage of labour</p></li>        
               <li type="square" class="bullets">
        <p class="bodytext"> reduces the need for surgical interventions</p></li>               <li type="square" class="bullets">
        <p class="bodytext">helps to keep baby calm and well oxygenated</p></li>
                   <li type="square" class="bullets">
        <p class="bodytext"> eaves you and baby feeling calm but alert and able to fully experience those special first few hours together </p></li>
                   <li type="square" class="bullets">
        <p class="bodytext"> empowers you and your birth partner to remain calm and in control even if there are unexpected circumstances</p></li>

        </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="width35_percent">
<div class="headerStretch">
<div class="image-pad-lefttop"><img src="images/grey-baby.jpg" width="265" height="177" /></div></div></div>

<div class="width15_percent">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="clear_both">
<div class="width_100_percent">
<br />
<br />
<div class="width15_percent">&nbsp;</div>
<div align="center" class="width70_percent">
    <div align="left">
      <h2 class="contentsubheadings">The common view</h2>

    </div>
     <p class= "bodytext" align="left"> 
Unfortunately the view that labour and birth are painful and traumatic continues to be one which is still widely circulated in the media. Even amongst well meaning friends and family the negative view often persists and pregnant women are frequently bombarded with negative and fear evoking images and stories..</p>

</div>
<div class="width15_percent">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>





<div class="clear_both">
<div class="width_100_percent">
<div class="width50_percentquotes-right">
<img src="images/open-quotes.jpg" width="30" height="20" alt=""/> My son was born at 4:50am. I sat back having been on all fours, and just stared at him swimming up on his back, eyes open in the water. The midwife had to prompt me to pick him up. I came out of this trance-like state and I scooped him up and suddenly the power of speech returned and I felt euphoric. <br />
AB -hypno-birthing Mum <img src="images/close-quotes.jpg" width="30" height="20" alt=""/></div>
<div align="left" class="width35_percent">
    <br />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="width15_percent">&nbsp;</div>
</div>




</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which bottom div are you referring to?

Comment: Hi sorry - it's this one: you can see at birthgently.co.uk/about-hypnobirthing.html

It's the quote - I tried to paste the code but it said I'd overrun on space.

Comment: This is very confusing and it's almost impossible to help you with this.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to keep the whole page white, right down to the bottom.

Comment: Add overflow: hidden; to .wrapper and the white will go the bottom.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to .wrapper

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look at this and cant see what is or isn't happening as desired.  Take a look at this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ajb6u/) I've added border the main container and bottom div and it is sitting within the container.

Take a look yourself, add this css to your page to see whats going on

```
#container
{
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.width15_percent
{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Ok - added it. I'm not much wiser - the container appears to run the whole length of the page? Thank you for looking at this...

Comment: but on the live version the blue only extends halfway down the page.

Comment: Yes that's my point.  the borders are just so you can (while developing) what elements are where on your page.  You were initially saying that the bottom div was falling out of the main wrapper.  This should show that that is not the case.  or correct me if I've misunderstood.

Comment: Is there another style sheet that you haven't shown?  are there are elements that are floating within the #container div?  if so, try putting a clearing div <div class="clear"></div> with a style of clear:both; right at the end before the closing </div> tag for #container.

Comment: The container div has 'content' and wrapper' within it - there are 3 css sheets associated with the document - I'll try and add them now. The overflow: hidden worked to keep the white running down the page, but your advice has highlighted that I must have another error going on here too....